# AngularJs behavior button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have  a button:

```
 <button  data-ng-click="toggleElement(asset)"   class="btn"><span class="text-center">Add To Cart</span></button>
```

I would like to hide this button when this element will add in a list  and show
a disable button with the title "Added to Cart"!!

I tried it :

```
<table class="table" data-ng-show="elements!=null && elements.length>0">
  <tr  data-ng-repeat="element in elements">          
            <td> 
            <button  data-ng-click="toggleElements(element)"  ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="isDisabled"  class="btn"><span class="text-center">Add To Cart</span></button>
    <td> <button data-ng-click="toggleAsset(elements[$index])" data-ng-disabled="added" class="btn">{{added ? 'Added' : 'Add'}}</button>             
</td> 
 </tr>

    </table>
```

in my controller I have this :

```
$scope.toggleElements= function (element){
        .....
           $scope.added  = true;
}
```

Somebody can help me...

Comment: What have you tried? Angular documentation should be more than enough to answer this question with the added bonus of learning the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
<button ng-click="toggleElement(asset)" ng-disabled="asset.added">{{asset.added ? 'Added' : 'Add'}}</button>
```

You'll need to set the property **asset.added** inside the *toggleElement()* method.

Comment: I have asset.added undefined...How can I add it!!! It is possible that I have to put ng-model="assets[$index].added" ??

Comment: Remember that if you are inside a ng-repeat you don't need to use the $index variable. You can just grab the current item being iterated and use it.

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution.

Have a look to the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDjKf2ONTIQ04Kp0D6Zp?p=preview)

```
<button ng-repeat="a in [0,1,2]" data-ng-click="added = !added" class="btn" ng-disabled="added">
  <span ng-show="!added" class="text-center">Add To Cart</span>
  <span ng-show="added" class="text-center">Added To Cart</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute several instructions inside one `ng-click` directive.
Just separate them with `;` like a normal javascript expression.

For example:

```
<button ng-click="doIt(); hide = true" ng-hide="hide">
  click me!
</button>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the hide variable is assigned to the current scope. If you are outside a ng-repeat or other directive, which create isolated scopes, you can leak this variable to other elements. This is also complicate unit testing, you are putting part of the logic on the view...

Comment: This will define a variable `$scope.hide` which will be shared by all assets, so if it's used in a list, it will hide all buttons, not just one. While not clear from the OP's question, I think it's safe to assume that there's a a list of assets

Comment: @mnemosyn disagree with you. It won't hide all buttons. Check my plunkr.

Comment: @gab: true, but that's because `ng-repeat` creates an isolated scope. If you simply copy the button, they'll interact. William Lepinski's comment already points that out.

Comment: @user880386: use William Lepinski's approach where the hidden property is stored on the object rather than the scope.

Comment: @mnemosyn:I tried but element.added is undefined....in My method toggleElement I just set elementi.added=true;tomorrow I will retry it...thanks